# Is it possible to create a progress bar/widget for a contribution page?

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, widget

Prior to CiviCRM, I used to use the give donation plugin which made a cool little progress bar for our fundraising campaign pages.  Looking to create something similar with CiviCRM, I came across the [CiviWCI](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civiwci) extension, but it only supports CiviCRM 4.4 and has not been updated in some time.

Is there a built in functionality or an alternative extension that I could use?

Many thanks!

Comment: it helps if someone can prove that the extension you refer to is broken for 4.7.x - have you done so?

Comment: also are you aware the Confirmation page can be turned off, per Contribution page, which kind of gets the process down to 2 windows, the one you submit, and the thank you one, at which point how useful is a progress bar?

Comment: Hey @petednz-fuzion, sorry, I should clarify, what I mean by progress bar is campaign progress... such as 3k of 5k raised.

Comment: ok. got you. a widget. see below

Comment: Related Gitlab issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We published a small extension that makes it easy to display the progress bar directly on the same contribution page: [contributeprogress](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/contributeprogress/tree/master).

[image: screenshot of the widget]

The README.md has more details, but the short version is that once this extension is enabled, you can enable the widget and tweak a few colours. The widget will be displayed directly on the contribution page. Not all of the widget settings are relevant (for example, we do not display the widget title and text body, because it's often redundant with the page introduction text).

The default design is also a bit different that the widget preview, because we wanted something a bit more modern looking (and we wanted to propose something that works out of the box, without requiring a designer).

Credits: Roshani Kothari helped with the visual design picking some of the best elements of how progress bars are displayed on different websites, and Plastic Pollution Coalition helped to fund this work. We welcome feedback to refine and improve it further.

Comment: Can this only be shown on the contribution page but not elsewhere?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, that is what the extension does by default. Can you give an example of 'elsewhere'?

Comment: It is useful to promote the widget for instance, on a home page. Can the code be copied like the native civi contribution widget?

Comment: Oh ok, no, it does not replace/improve the existing widget. It shouldn't be too difficult to re-create an equivalent result, if you are interested in contributing a patch or sponsoring the work.

Comment: 2020 update: I released a new version that provides an alternative embeddable widget. You can see it in action here: https://civicrm.org/mih

Answer (score 3):

Set your Goal Amount on Contribution Page = Title and Settings

> Enter an optional goal amount for this contribution page (e.g. for this 'campaign'). If you enable a contribution widget for this page, the widget will track progress against this goal. Otherwise, the goal will display as 'no limit'.

Then click through to the Widget tab such as this one on demo: http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/widget?reset=1&action=update&id=1

Comment: It would be great if a progress-bar could be placed directly on the live contribution page.  Could you provide a specific example of how to incorporate the widget code directly into the contribution-page "Introductory Message" HTML?

Comment: Widget documentation is here but presume you made effort to check that already?? https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/widgets/

Comment: Yes I have looked at that documentation.  It doesn't indicate how specifically to get the widget source-code into the live contribution page, and simply pasting it into the "Introductory Message" section of the contribution-page configuration screen does not work.

Comment: Can you pls ask a new question and spell out the exact steps you took and what 'does not work' actually means? I just tried on dmaster and had no joy either.